# why doesn't ubuntu 15.10 support wireless internet like puppy linux?

Tags: drivers

downloaded and tried usb ubuntu 15.10-  it operates well, but it can't see the wireless card?, so no wireless internet connection.  other distros include utilities that work and find wireless internet, why not ubuntu?

the wireless is Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6205 Wi-Fi adapter